# Q: Convert PARQUET to JSON in C++ by Apache Arrow?

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

I can read the **Parquet** file to Arrow::table in **c++** now, but have no idea how to convert them to the **JSON** file.

Is there any example to do that by **Apache Arrow** or something convenient else?

Thanks~

Answer (score -1):

You can read Parquet into pandas dataframe and convert to JSON by using Python's [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)
.